# Cognitive services text translation authentication issue

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

I'm utilizing Azure's Cognitive Services Text Analysis API. I'm attempting to authenticate by passing my secret key for an access token via these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference

I POST my Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key to https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken and get the following error:

{"error":{"code":"401","message": "The issueToken Operation under Token API V1.0 API is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier TextAnalytics.S."}}

I'm performing this authentication request using The Info Lab's macro in Alteryx - https://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2017/09/26/translate-foreign-language-text-alteryx/ - I had to edit URL in the macro to add the "eastus" as the region in the issueToken request. Before I did that, I was getting an AccessDenied error response. At least now I know it's logging on to my resource because it will change the last letter in the error from "F" (free) to "S" to "S1" which are the pricing tiers I was switching between.

I have a pay-as-you-go subscription and I switched the resource to use Free, S, and S0 pricing tiers. Still always getting the same error. Please help!

Thank you

All provided in my summary.

I expect to get an authenticated token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, you want to use Azure translator API and want to get an authenticated token specified by region. Based [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#multi-service-subscription) mentioned , if you want to get a region based token, you should use [Cognitive Service’s multi-service subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account?tabs=multiservice%2Cwindows) . You can create a multi-service subscription by [this link](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesAllInOne) and you can get a token by its region and key as below :

[image]

For differences between Single-service resource and Multi-service resource , as official mentioned :

> **Multi-service resource:**
>   Access multiple Azure Cognitive Services with
>   a single key and endpoint. Consolidates billing from the services you
>   use.
>
> **Single-service resource:**
>   Access a single Azure Cognitive Service
>   with a unique key and endpoint for each service created. Use the free
>   tier to try out the service.

As we know except for translation service , there are many other services on Azure cognitive service . So when you create a Multi-service resource , you can call all Azure Cognitive Services . If you just need one or two kind Azure Cognitive Services or you want to get a separate billing of them, you can create Single-service resources separately.

In a wold, the differences between them is more about management instead of service.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! This worked and I am authenticating now. Can you provide a little more explanation about the subscription I just got and the difference between what I was originally working with? I had originally followed this post https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Knowledge-Base/The-How-to-Guide-to-Cognitive-Services-Text-Analytics-Macro/ta-p/45175

Comment: Hi @Neil,the resource the doc mentioned is a Single-service resource , it could call text analysis service only . I have updated answer .If it helps you , pls mark this answer so that it will help others who has the similar issue , thank you !

Comment: Thank you, this makes it absolutely clear. I'm connecting now and taking advantage of Azure Cognitive. I marked your comment as the answer.